# Java why can't I use multiple inheritance with functional interfaces

Tags: java, lambda, polymorphism

I was making a small library for Java, and part of the api was a functional interface (and thus, lambda expressions) that took 3 arguments. I realized that two of them might often be unwanted. So I thought to make something like this:

```
class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    call((s) -> System.out.println(s));
  }

  static void call(A a) {
    a.call(7, 42, "Hello World!");
  }

  static interface A {

    void call(int x, int y, String s);

  }

  static interface B extends A {

    void call(String s);

    default void call(int x, int y, String s) {
      call(s);
    }

  }

}
```

I expected that users could then insert the first two parameters if they wanted, but if they didn't they could leave them out and they would be ignored. However, when I tried to compile the above code, I got a compile-time exception with the message "incompatible types: incompatible parameter types in lambda expression". Why does this not work?

Comment: Your code works fine if you just [cast the lambda to `(B)`](https://ideone.com/AO1KKo). Otherwise it's just assuming you're creating an object that only implements `A`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `static void call(A a)` method requires a parameter of type `A`, or a lambda expression that satisfies the [SAM method](https://www.quora.com/What-is-a-Single-Abstract-Method-SAM-interface-in-Java-8) signature that you have defined on it. That's why it will complain that you are just passing 1 parameter when it is actually expecting 3. If you want to pass a lambda expression of type `B` you must cast it first like this:

```
call((B)(s) -> System.out.println(s));
```

Or you can edit your `static void call` method to accept a parameter of type `B`.

Answer (score 1):

The method `call(A a)` takes instance of interface `A` as an argument and in interface `A` the method call is taking 3 arguments: `void call(int x, int y, String s);` so it looks like you want to declare your argument as an instance of interface `B` - not `A`

So modifying:

```
static void call(A a) {
    a.call(7, 42, "Hello World!");
 }
```

to:

```
static void call(B b) {
    b.call(7, 42, "Hello World!");
 }
```

will solve the issue